# "smart" ansi-term on start-up?

Tags: start-up, ansi-term

I have the following line in my `.init.el`

```
(ansi-term "/usr/bin/bash")
```

, because I **usually** like to have a terminal running in my emacs. The problem is that **sometimes** I don't, for instance, when I just do some quick edit, like when I `git commit`. In this case, exiting emacs involves prompts about running processes, and **usually** I like these safety warnings. I know I can create an `alias` something along the lines of

```
alias emax='emacs --eval "(ansi-term \"/usr/bin/bash\")"'
```

This leaves the normal `emacs` command unchanged and everything would be fine, if I **only** start emacs from terminals. If I want to start it from the "Start" menu however, then I'm out of luck again.

So, the question is, is there some clever mechanism, where emacs **usually** starts with an `ansi-term`, but somehow knows, when I don't want one. One such possibility would be creating something like a custom `emax.desktop` file, but I'd also have to use the `alias` above and I'd like to avoid maintaining code in two different places.

So hopefully this question is understandable. I'm open to any linuxy hints, but simpler is better of course.

Comment: You could turn `emax` into a bash script that `exec`s emacs with the appropriate arguments, and then have a desktop shortcut to that script.

Comment: Why not use `emacsclient` for things like `git commit`?

Answer (score 2):

Paste this script into bash and you are ready to roll:

```
#!/bin/bash
EMAX_DIR=/usr/local/bin
EMAX=$EMAX_DIR/emax
mkdir -p $EMAX_DIR
cat > $EMAX <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
exec emacs \$* --eval "(ansi-term \"/usr/bin/bash\")"
EOF
chmod +x $EMAX
hash -r

SHORTCUT=$HOME/.local/share/applications/emacs-with-ansi-term.desktop
sed -e "s,EMAX,$EMAX," > $SHORTCUT <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacs with Ansi Terminal
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;
Exec=EMAX %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
Encoding=UTF-8
Keywords=emax;emacs;Text;Editor;Terminal
EOF
```

This assumes that you are using a freedesktop.org-compliant desktop like GNOME.  It will make the `emax` bash script and also create the desktop shortcut for invoking it.